# Registration problems when using heroku

Tags: heroku, server

I have a problem uploading my project on heroku; I am following a tutorial and everything is going well, in the cmd I place "heroku" and version, usage and commands appear.
But there is something strange, that when I put "heroku login" my email account appears but not to put my password, I want to put mkdir and the name I want to create and "access denied" appears

I just created my account a couple of minutes ago, do I have to wait for this error to not appear? Did I do something wrong when I registered? How do I know if there is an error in my account?

[image]

Comment: Why are you in ``C:\Program Files\``? That's a protected system directory and you have no business changing things in there. Windows is _protecting you_ by preventing you from creating that directory. Try working in ``C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\`` or something instead.

Comment: ok thank you very much, I thought it was something else because during the installation an error window appeared and then as if nothing happened the heroku window already logged in